# Importing Configurable Product in Magento

Tags: php, magento-1.9

I would like to import configurable product in Magento through CSV file. In this regard I tried to follow this [tutorial](http://magentorocks.blogspot.com/2012/11/import-configurable-products-with-their.html)

But the product appears as simple product. Could anyone help me in this regard ?? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

personally I use magmi for imports in magento, If you need to make advanced imports i d suggest you to use it, it is easy to set up and nice in performances.

For your actual problem, did you set the type_id to configurable?